# innerHTML not working and js is activated

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio, google-chrome

I just started learning js(newbie) for the first time, so while i was learning from a youtube channel, i was writing my code as well but now i noticed when i wrote document.getElementById("p1").innnerHTML ="Hello" + firstname; in vscode editor it was meant to run on my chrome browser but it is not. Although i can read my code on console in devTools for more clarification document.getElementById("p1").innnerHTML ="Hello" + firstname; was written in js file and also js has been activated. pls what can i do to let innerHTML run in my browser?

Comment: First of all, `innnerHTML` isn't correct; you need `innerHTML`. Next, have you checked your browser's dev tools for errors?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and learn from a reputable source. Most online tutorials are going to teach you outdated or flat out wrong things. For example, you should not be using `innerHTML` in this case as there are security and performance concerns with it. Instead, you should be using `textContent`.

Comment: Thanks but I've been using freecodecamp YouTube channel only recently I decided to learn from brocode on YouTube but so far I've been using YouTube to learn coding.

Comment: Yes, and that's a mistake. You are going to wind up "learning" all sorts of incorrect things and bad habits. Your question here shows that.

Comment: You are right but all am trying to do is to write HTML file in js

Comment: Yes, and you spelled `innerHTML` wrong and shouldn't be using `.innerHTML` in the first place.

Comment: Change `.innnerHTML` to `textContent`. Also, when you post here, post all the relevant code (including HTML).

Comment: True but in my code it was well-written

Comment: As I said, we can't help you if you don't post ALL the relevant code.